# Psycopg2 could not be found when executing .exe created with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, psycopg2

I'm building a python exe with Pyinstaller and it works fine but when i try to execute the compiled version of my program it Fails.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
[16803] Failed to execute script main
```

I have tried to run the command but doesn't works

```
 pyinstaller ../Main/main.py --hidden-import=psycopg2 --onefile
```

Here i leave the main.spec file

```
 # -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['../Main/main.py'],
             pathex=['/home/eureka/Documents/ETL_Yalla/Exe'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=['psycopg2'],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='main',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```